# How to PUT image downloaded with ASIHTTPrequest in a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

i want to display an image downloaded with ASIHTTPrequest in a UIIamgeView . I tried this :

```
NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
    promotionPicture.image = responseData;
```

But don't work , incompatible type ... help Please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you'll need to wrap the `NSData` in a `UIImage`:

```
promotionPicture.image = [UIImage imageWithData:responseData];
```

Comment: Strange, this does not work for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269105/load-gif-image-from-web-using-asihttp-in-objective-c